# How to make zurb foundation off canvas menu fixed?

Tags: css, navigation, zurb-foundation

I have a fixed tab bar and the problem is when you scroll down the site and click the mobile menu icon you have to scroll back up to see the navigation.

Does any one have a solution to this or an idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/17704-off-canvas-menu---fixed-position-header---scrolling

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Foundation 5 off-canvas navigation menu sticky?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107926/how-to-make-foundation-5-off-canvas-navigation-menu-sticky)